# Regexp working on RegExr(http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) but not in PHP preg_match

Tags: php, regex, string

What i have here is a regular expression that must match html anchor tags and extract them from the string.

```
<a(.*)href=[\'A-Za-z0-9\"@?+:\-_.\/]+( *)[\'A-Za-z0-9\"@?+:\-_.-=\/ ]+( *)>( *)[\'A-Za-z0-9\"@?+:\-_.-=\/ ]*( *)</( *)a>
```

It works on RegExr(http://gskinner.com/RegExr/) but when i try it with preg_match_all()
LIke this:

```
preg_match_all('#<a(.*)href=[\'A-Za-z0-9\"@?+:\-_.\/]+( *)[\'A-Za-z0-9\"@?+:\-_.-=\/ ]+( *)>( *)[\'A-Za-z0-9\"@?+:\-_.-=\/ ]*( *)</( *)a>#i',$string,$matches);
```

it returns empty arrays. i.e. no results :(

Any help and correctios are welcome.

Comment: You're parsing HTML with regex. Don't.

Comment: i'm just doing this for practice ... How else can i parse it then?

Comment: The regex works, it just won't match *every* HTML variation. Since you didn't post an example of that, it's pretty much unanswerable.

Comment: since i'm new to REGEXP i'm experimenting. ANd ( *) seems to work for spaces

Comment: @hussain PHP has a series of classes that implement the DOM: http://php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php That's by far the best way to traverse HTML.

Comment: @lonesomeday thanx for the link but can you just look at it thoroughly and tell me whats right and wrong ... u can take your time as i'm just experimenting ... you can just mail me later with the corrections...

Comment: @hussain You need to post the $string you're trying to match.

Comment: You're going to create confusion by asking for help matching anchor tags. *Tags* are the angle bracketed parts. Your regular expression seems to be matching complete anchor *elements* which consist of a start tag, content, and an end tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your first problem is that you are not giving the same regular expression to `preg_match_all` that you are giving to `RegExr`.

In PHP's single-quoted string literals, `\` is treated specially when it precedes either another `\` or a `'`. In those two cases, the `\` is a prefix escape which lets the `\` or `'` be inserted into the string.

So, wherever you have `\` or `'` in your regular expression, you must use `\\` and `\'` in your single-quoted string literal, so that they get passed to `preg_match_all`.

For example, where you have `\'` you must use `\\\'`.

Comment: Thanx man, it works now. escaping the \' was the problem.Although i still have to find a way around to make it include only url's.